# Type conversion settings missed in Azure Data Factory in Copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to use option allowDataTruncation from Type conversion settings in Copy activity in Azure Data Factory, but this option is missed. In my pipeline, in one copy activity source(Postgres), sink (parquet, adls) I can use it, but in another copy activity source(parquet, adls), sink (synapse) I dont see this option. Why is that?

1
[image]

2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In copy activity, the `Type conversion settings` are not supported for both `Copy command` and `Polybase` copy methods.

These settings for synapse or only supported for `Bulk insert` or `Upsert` copy methods.

[image]

[image]

So, to use the type conversion settings in copy activity, you need to use Bulk insert copy method.

Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67745594) by @[GregGalloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070440/greggalloway) to undertstand about these copy methods.